# How to pass XML data in api - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hope all are safe and good.

My question is a how to pass XML data in api react native. i'm try to find out solution but i'm not getting proper solution. Can anyone share details step by step.

Thank you in Advance and help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know React, but here is some info
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fetch-and-populate-xml-data-in-react-native